# Скрыть контекстное меню если есть цикл

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-context-menu

Имеется `RecyclerView`, в нём по задумке по долгому нажатию на пункт появляется контекстное меню с двумя пунктами. Первый удаляет один пункт в списке и работает без применения цикла. При этом контекстное меню исчезает сразу после клика на меню. А если выбран пункт, где предусмотрен цикл `while`, то само контекстное меню не пропадает. Приходится ткнуть в любую другую область экрана. Прошу помочь сделать скрытие меню сразу после клика по его пункту именно в ситуации когда используется цикл.

**Показан участок кода с циклом:**

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
    {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < mDataset.size())
        {
        i++;
        if (mDataset.get(i).get("UserId").equals(mDataset.get(getAdapterPosition()).get("UserId")))
            {
            mDataset.remove(i);
            notifyItemRemoved(i);
            i--;
            }
        }
    return true;
    }
```

[image: скриншот]